# What's an easy way to read random line from a file?

Tags: shell, random

What's an easy way to read random line from a file in a shell script?

Comment: Is  each line padded to a fixed length?

Comment: no, each line has variable number of characters

Comment: large file: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29102589/get-random-lines-from-large-files-in-bash

Answer (score 395):

You can use `shuf`:

```
shuf -n 1 $FILE
```

There is also a utility called `rl`. In Debian it's in the `randomize-lines` package that does exactly what you want, though not available in all distros.  On its home page it actually recommends the use of `shuf` instead (which didn't exist when it was created, I believe).  `shuf` is part of the GNU coreutils, `rl` is not.

```
rl -c 1 $FILE
```

Comment: i really like that shuf approach!

Comment: Thanks for the `shuf` tip, it's built-in in Fedora.

Comment: Does this `r1` have any advantages? `shuf` seams to work perfectly!

Comment: shuf is great as a drop-in replacement for head command, good to know

Comment: Andalso, `sort -R` is definitely going to make one wait **a lot** if dealing with considerably huge files -- 80kk lines --, whereas, `shuf -n` acts quite instantaneously.

Comment: You can get shuf on OS X by installing `coreutils` from Homebrew.
Might be called `gshuf` instead of `shuf`.

Comment: Similarly, you can use `randomize-lines` on OS X by `brew install randomize-lines; rl -c 1 $FILE`

Comment: @Rubens: [the same question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9245638/select-random-lines-from-a-file-in-bash/9245733#comment40761869_9245733)

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: [the same answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9245638/select-random-lines-from-a-file-in-bash/9245733#comment40766527_9245733)

Comment: @ThomasAhle, the Debian package summary for `r1`'s randomize-lines states *Users are recommended to use the shuf command instead which should be available by default. This package may be considered deprecated.*  Therefore, `shuf` appears preferable.

Comment: Note that `shuf` is part of [GNU Coreutils](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Core_Utilities) and therefore won't necessarily be available (by default) on *BSD systems (or Mac?).  @Tracker1's perl one-liner below is more portable (and by my tests, is slightly faster).

Comment: Why is this answer in the bottom though it has the most upvotes?

Comment: @kouton are you sorting by age?

Comment: This is a cool command! Yet another wheel I've reinvented not knowing it already exists in my flavor of Unix! Thank you!

Comment: though this is not suitable for huge files... I'm getting a 'shuf: read error: Cannot allocate memory' on a 70GB file

Comment: This is a great answer. I would just like to point out that in case more than 1 line is needed, ``shuf`` and ``rl`` make *permutations* of lines, not random draws. I.e. if you want to draw k random lines, you will want to run ``shuf -n 1`` k times. This will draw from N^k possibilities instead of N!/(N-k)! possibilities, where N is the total number of lines. E.g., get 7 random lines from wordlist.txt: ``for n in {1..7}; do shuf -n1 wordlist.txt; done``

Comment: you can use process substitution if you don't want to give `shuf` a file: `shuf -n 1 <(echo -e "heads\ntails")` will randomly pick "heads" or "tails".

Or just pipe to it: `echo -e "heads\ntails" | shuf -n 1`

Answer (score 74):

Another alternative:

```
head -$((${RANDOM} % `wc -l < file` + 1)) file | tail -1
```

Comment: ${RANDOM} only generates numbers less than 32768, so don't use this for large files (for example the English dictionary).

Comment: This does not give you the precise same probability for every line, due to the modulo operation. This does barely matter if the file length is << 32768 (and not at all if it divides that number), but maybe worth noting.

Comment: You can extend this to 30-bit random numbers by using `(${RANDOM} << 15) + ${RANDOM}`. This significantly reduces the bias and allows it to work for files containing up to 1 billion lines.

Comment: @nneonneo: Very cool trick, though according to this link it should be OR'ing the ${RANDOM}'s instead of PLUS'ing http://stackoverflow.com/a/19602060/293064

Comment: `+` and `|` are the same since `${RANDOM}` is 0..32767 by definition.

Comment: There's a heavy performance penalty to this, since it needs to count lines to be sure it's reading to the right point.

Answer (score 74):

```
sort --random-sort $FILE | head -n 1
```

(I like the shuf approach above even better though - I didn't even know that existed and I would have never found that tool on my own)

Comment: +1 I like it, but you may need a very recent `sort`, didn't work on any of my systems (CentOS 5.5, Mac OS 10.7.2). Also, useless use of cat, could be reduced to `sort --random-sort < $FILE | head -n 1`

Comment: `sort -R <<< $'1\n1\n2' | head -1` is as likely to return 1 and 2, because `sort -R` sorts duplicate lines together. The same applies to `sort -Ru`, because it removes duplicate lines.

Comment: This is relatively slow, since the whole file needs to get shuffled by `sort` before piping it to `head`. `shuf` selects random lines from the file, instead and is much faster for me.

Comment: @SteveKehlet while we're at it, `sort --random-sort $FILE | head` would be best, as it allows it to access the file directly, possibly enabling efficient parallel sorting

Comment: @WaelJ Good improvement!

Comment: The `--random-sort` and `-R` options are specific to GNU sort (so they won't work with BSD or Mac OS `sort`). GNU sort learned those flags in 2005 so you need GNU coreutils 6.0 or newer (eg CentOS 6).

Comment: from Wikipedia: "this is not a full random shuffle because it will sort identical lines together"

Comment: @Bengt: nothing is written until `shuf` reads the whole file into memory. `sort` may work even if the file does not fit in memory.

Answer (score 31):

This is simple.

```
cat file.txt | shuf -n 1
```

Granted this is just a tad slower than the "shuf -n 1 file.txt" on its own.

Comment: Best answer. I didn't know about this command. Note that `-n 1` specifies 1 line, and you can change it to more than 1. `shuf` can be used for other things too; I just piped `ps aux` and `grep` with it to randomly kill processes partially matching a name.

Answer (score 20):

[perlfaq5: How do I select a random line from a file?](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq5.html#How-do-I-select-a-random-line-from-a-file%3f) Here's a reservoir-sampling algorithm from the Camel Book:

```
perl -e 'srand; rand($.) < 1 && ($line = $_) while <>; print $line;' file
```

This has a significant advantage in space over reading the whole file in. You can find a proof of this method in The Art of Computer Programming, Volume 2, Section 3.4.2, by Donald E. Knuth.

Comment: Just for the purposes of inclusion (in case the referred site goes down), here's the code that Tracker1 pointed to:


"cat filename | perl -e 'while (<>) { push(@_,$_); } print @_[rand()*@_];';"

Comment: This is a useless use of cat.
Here's a slight modification of the code found in perlfaq5 (and courtesy of the Camel book):
perl -e 'srand; rand($.) < 1 && ($line = $_) while <>; print $line;' filename

Comment: err... the linked site, that is

Comment: I just benchmarked an N-lines version of this code against `shuf`.  The perl code is very slightly faster (8% faster by user time, 24% faster by system time), though anecdotally I've found the perl code "seems" less random (I wrote a jukebox using it).

Comment: More food for thought:  [`shuf` stores the whole input file in memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9245638/select-random-lines-from-a-file-in-bash/9245733#comment40771587_9245733), which is a horrible idea, while this code only stores one line, so the limit of this code is a line count of INT_MAX (2^31 or 2^63 depending on your arch), assuming any of its selected potential lines fits in memory.

Comment: here's the awk equivalent. either of these answers (perl or awk) are better than the accepted for - portability, speed, and ability to manage huge files easily.                                                                        

`awk 'BEGIN{srand()}{rand()*NR<1&&l=$0}END{print l}'  file`

or                                                                                                     

`some_input | awk 'BEGIN{srand()}{rand()*NR<1&&l=$0}END{print l}'`

Answer (score 11):

using a bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
# replace with file to read
FILE=tmp.txt
# count number of lines
NUM=$(wc - l < ${FILE})
# generate random number in range 0-NUM
let X=${RANDOM} % ${NUM} + 1
# extract X-th line
sed -n ${X}p ${FILE}
```

Comment: Random can be 0, sed needs 1 for the first line. sed -n 0p returns error.

Comment: mhm - how about $1 for "tmp.txt" and $2 for NUM ?

Comment: but even with the bug worth a point, as it does not need perl or python and is as efficient as you can get (reading the file exactly twice but not into memory - so it would work even with huge files).

Comment: @asalamon74: thanks
@blabla999: if we make a function out of it, ok for $1, but why not computing NUM?

Comment: Changing the sed line to:

head -${X} ${FILE} | tail -1

should do it

Comment: useless use of cat detected, wc happily takes files directly

Comment: @Hasturkun: beware - the output of wc depends on whether it reads stdin or a file name off its command line.  Granted, 'wc -l < $FILE' would be OK; using 'wc -l $FILE' (no redirection) would be a bug.

Comment: @Hasturkun & J.Leffler: the cat was meant to avoid wc printing the file name. Fixed with the 'wc -l < $FILE' suggestion, thanks

Comment: The variable names should be quoted, especially `$FILE`. The curly braces are superfluous here. I recommend using lowercase or mixed-case variable names to avoid potential name collisions with shell or environment variables.

Comment: If a file has 32769 or more lines, the last ones are never selected. `wc - l` shouldn't have a space.

Answer (score 4):

Single bash line:

```
sed -n $((1+$RANDOM%`wc -l test.txt | cut -f 1 -d ' '`))p test.txt
```

Slight problem: duplicate filename.

Comment: slighter problem. performing this on /usr/share/dict/words tends to favor words starting with "A". Playing with it, I'm at about 90% "A" words to 10% "B" words. None starting with numbers yet, which make up the head of the file.

Comment: `wc -l < test.txt` avoids having to pipe to `cut`.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a simple Python script that will do the job:

```py
import random, sys
lines = open(sys.argv[1]).readlines()
print(lines[random.randrange(len(lines))])
```

Usage:

```
python randline.py file_to_get_random_line_from
```

Comment: This doesn't quite work. It stops after a single line. To make it work, I did this: `import random, sys                                                              
lines = open(sys.argv[1]).readlines() `                                          
for i in range(len(lines)):                                                     
    rand = random.randint(0, len(lines)-1)                                      
    print lines.pop(rand),

Comment: Stupid comment system with crappy formatting. Didn't formatting in comments work once upon a time?

Comment: randint is inclusive therefore `len(lines)` may lead to IndexError. You could use `print(random.choice(list(open(sys.argv[1]))))`. There is also memory efficient [reservoir sampling algorithm](http://askubuntu.com/a/527778/3712).

Comment: Quite space hungry; consider a 3TB file.

Comment: @MichaelCampbell: [reservoir sampling algorithm](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32792504/4279) that I've mentioned above may work with 3TB file (if line size is limited).

Comment: Using [py](https://github.com/Russell91/pythonpy) is nice. `-l` assigns incoming lines to a list, `l`. `py` auto-imports stdlib modules. so you can do `cat $FILE | py -l "random.choice(l)"`. Try it: `python -m this | py -l "random.choice(l)"` ... erm actually just `py this | py -l "random.choice(l)"` ;)

Answer (score 2):

Another way using '**awk**'

```
awk NR==$((${RANDOM} % `wc -l < file.name` + 1)) file.name
```

Comment: That uses awk and bash (`$RANDOM` is a [bashism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bashism)).  Here is a pure awk (mawk) method using the same logic as @Tracker1's cited perlfaq5 code above: `awk 'rand() * NR < 1 { line = $0 } END { print line }' file.name` (wow, it's even *shorter* than the perl code!)

Comment: That code must read the file (`wc`) in order to get a line count, then must read (part of) the file again (`awk`) to get the content of the given random line number.  I/O will be far more expensive than getting a random number.  My code reads the file once only.  The issue with awk's `rand()` is that it seeds based on seconds, so you'll get duplicates if you run it consecutively too fast.

Answer (score 1):

A solution that also works on MacOSX, and should also works on Linux(?):

```
N=5
awk 'NR==FNR {lineN[$1]; next}(FNR in lineN)' <(jot -r $N 1 $(wc -l < $file)) $file
```

Where:

- `N` is the number of random lines you want
- `NR==FNR {lineN[$1]; next}(FNR in lineN) file1 file2`
  --> save line numbers written in `file1` and then print corresponding line in `file2`
- `jot -r $N 1 $(wc -l < $file)` --> draw `N` numbers randomly (`-r`) in range `(1, number_of_line_in_file)` with `jot`. The process substitution `<()` will make it look like a file for the interpreter, so `file1` in previous example.

Answer (score 0):

Using only vanilla sed and awk, and without using $RANDOM, a simple, space-efficient and reasonably fast "one-liner" for selecting a single line pseudo-randomly from a file named FILENAME is as follows:

```
sed -n $(awk 'END {srand(); r=rand()*NR; if (r<NR) {sub(/\..*/,"",r); r++;}; print r}' FILENAME)p FILENAME
```

(This works even if FILENAME is empty, in which case no line is emitted.)

One possible advantage of this approach is that it only calls rand() once.

As pointed out by @AdamKatz in the comments, another possibility would be to call rand() for each line:

```
awk 'rand() * NR < 1 { line = $0 } END { print line }' FILENAME
```

(A simple proof of correctness can be given based on induction.)

#### Caveat about `rand()`

"In most awk implementations, including gawk, rand() starts generating numbers from the same starting number, or seed, each time you run awk."

-- https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Numeric-Functions.html

Comment: See [the comment I posted a year before this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448005/whats-an-easy-way-to-read-random-line-from-a-file-in-unix-command-line#comment43573811_18607080), which has a simpler awk solution that doesn't require sed. Also note my caveat about awk's random number generator, which seeds at whole seconds.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

IFS=$'\n' wordsArray=($(<$1))

numWords=${#wordsArray[@]}
sizeOfNumWords=${#numWords}

while [ True ]
do
    for ((i=0; i<$sizeOfNumWords; i++))
    do
        let ranNumArray[$i]=$(( ( $RANDOM % 10 )  + 1 ))-1
        ranNumStr="$ranNumStr${ranNumArray[$i]}"
    done
    if [ $ranNumStr -le $numWords ]
    then
        break
    fi
    ranNumStr=""
done

noLeadZeroStr=$((10#$ranNumStr))
echo ${wordsArray[$noLeadZeroStr]}
```

Comment: Since $RANDOM generates numbers less than the number of words in /usr/share/dict/words, which has 235886 (on my Mac anyway), I just generate 6 separate random numbers between 0 and 9 and string them together. Then I make sure that number is less than 235886. Then remove leading zeros to index the words that I stored in the array. Since each word is its own line this could easily be used for any file to randomly pick a line.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I discovery since my Mac OS doesn't use all the easy answers. I used the jot command to generate a number since the $RANDOM variable solutions seems not to be very random in my test.  When testing my solution I had a wide variance in the solutions provided in the output.

```
  RANDOM1=`jot -r 1 1 235886`
   #range of jot ( 1 235886 ) found from earlier wc -w /usr/share/dict/web2
   echo $RANDOM1
   head -n $RANDOM1 /usr/share/dict/web2 | tail -n 1
```

The echo of the variable is to get a visual of the generated random number.