# move files to a few directories in random order

Tags: bash, unix, solaris-10

I would like to move a lot of files from one directory to a few directories `dst/f0..dst/f9` in random order.

I tried to do it like this:

```
ls src/*.xml | head |  xargs -I {} mv {}  f$(($RANDOM % 10))
```

but all files has been moved into one directory src/fN

How I can to do it? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is fastest solution based on the @fedorqui solution. Thanks @fedorqui!

```
ls -1 -f | /usr/xpg4/bin/awk -v seed=$RANDOM 'BEGIN{srand(seed)} /\.xml$/ {printf "mv \"%s\" dst/f%d\n", $1, int(rand()*10)}' | sh
```

I measured speed  for this script. It works fast

```
date;ls -1 -f | /usr/xpg4/bin/awk -v seed=$RANDOM 'BEGIN{srand(seed)} /\.xml$/ {printf "mv \"%s\" dst/f%d\n", $1, int(rand()*10)}' > list.sh;date;cat list.sh | wc -l
```

Output for the script

```
Fri Jul 17 13:21:54 YEKT 2015
Fri Jul 17 13:21:54 YEKT 2015
29142
```

I understand parsing the output of `ls` maybe is not safe. But I don't need a portable solutions in this particular case

Answer (score 3):

The way you are writing it, `$RANDOM` is executed just once. Better generate a loop that calls it every time:

```
for file in src/*.xml
do
    mv "$file" "f$((RANDOM % 10))"
done
```

This way you also avoid parsing the output of `ls`, which is something [a bit dangerous](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

---

To speed this up, you can maybe use `awk`. If you have GNU awk, for example:

```
awk -v seed=$RANDOM 'BEGIN{srand(seed)} FNR==1{printf "mv \"%s\" dst/f%d\n", FILENAME, int(rand()*10); nextfile}' *
```

This uses `srand()` as described in [Random numbers generation with awk in BASH shell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4048538/1983854) and [`nextfile`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Nextfile-Statement.html).

This will write a file full of `mv file dir/` expressions, one per line. Then, just do `cat file | sh` to execute it.

Comment: I have ~160000 files in `src`
The script above can handle ~1000 files in ~10 mins
Can I speed up it? is it possible?

Comment: @DmitryZaytsev see my update with an `awk` suggestion. Note you need GNU awk, which I don't know if it is available in your Solaris 10. Try to use `/usr/xpg4/bin/awk`.

Comment: thank you! I just tried to implement your suggestion. `date;/usr/xpg4/bin/awk -v seed=$RANDOM 'BEGIN{srand(seed)} FNR==1{printf "mv \"%s\" dst/f%d\n", FILENAME, int(rand()*10); nextfile}' *.xml > list.sh;date;cat list.sh| wc -l`
the script above spent 14 mins for ~4000 files
`Fri Jul 17 08:42:34 YEKT 2015
^C
Fri Jul 17 08:56:49 YEKT 2015
    4089
`
I will look for the faster solution. Anyway thank you for your suggestion!

Comment: @DmitryZaytsev wow, that is incredibly slow :| Maybe you are using a busy filesystem?

Comment: I think awk performs some sorting files before handle them. A lot of files in the directory cause the delays. I tried to use `ls -f` for build unsorted the file list. It works.

Comment: @DmitryZaytsev nice to read that! It is also interesting what you mention about `But I don't need a portable solutions in this particular case`. So if you are entirely sure, do it : ) I like the `awk` solution because it also lets you see the file to be executed. This way, you can "debug" easily.

Comment: I meant I'm sure the file names in my case doesn't contains spaces or other separators. And awk variable `$1` will contain entire filename

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way using `xargs`.

```
ls src/*.xml | xargs -i bash -c 'mv {}  f$(($RANDOM % 10))'
```

It looks more straight but i would choose @fedorqui solution. `xargs` will spawn as many processes are there are inputs