# Choosing randomly between two possibilities

Tags: python, bash, random, awk

I have the following file:

```
452 0/0 10 30 40 
460 0/1 0 40 40
500 0/0 5 35 40
600 0/1 15 25 40
800 1/1 40 0 40
```

The real file contains millions of lines. If the second field is 0/0, I print the 3rd and 5th columns. If the second field is 1/1, I print the 4th and 5th columns. Using this command:

```
awk 'BEGIN{OFS="\t"}{ if($2=="0/0") {print $1, $2, $3, $5} else if($2=="1/1") {print $1, $2, $4, $5}}' file
```

The problem is that when the second field is 0/1. I want to randomly choose 0 or 1, if chosen 0, print 3rd and 5th columns and if chosen 1, print 4th and 5th columns.

Is there a way to randomly choose 0 or 1 every time there is a 0/1? The code could be in awk, bash or python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the [Random numbers generation with awk in BASH shell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4048538/1983854) trick by paxdiablo, you can say:

```
awk -v seed=$RANDOM 'BEGIN {srand(seed)}
          $2=="0/0" {chosen=3}
          $2=="1/1" {chosen=4}
          $2=="0/1" {chosen=3+int(rand()+0.5)}
          {print $chosen, $5}' file
```

In `chosen` we store either 3 or 4. With `chosen=3+int(rand()+0.5)` we get either 3 or 4.

Let's see it work:

```
$ awk -v seed=$RANDOM 'BEGIN {srand(seed)} $2=="0/0" {chosen=3} $2=="1/1" {chosen=4} $2=="0/1" {chosen=3+int(rand()+0.5)} {print $chosen, $5}' a
10 40
40 40
5 40
25 40
0 40
$ awk -v seed=$RANDOM 'BEGIN {srand(seed)} $2=="0/0" {chosen=3} $2=="1/1" {chosen=4} $2=="0/1" {chosen=3+int(rand()+0.5)} {print $chosen, $5}' a
10 40
40 40
5 40
15 40
0 40
```

Comment: Thanks! But this chooses either 0 or 1 for the whole file. What's needed is to choose 0 or 1 randomly at each encounter with 0/1 for each line.

Comment: You need to use srand in BEGIN block or you will always have the same "random" number for the duration of the program.

Comment: @Homap yeeep, there was a mistake on my random generation. Now it is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

A solution using python: you could use `random` and point to a list containing `0` and `1`

```
import random

binaryChoice = ['0','1']
field = ('0/1')
if field == ('0/1'):
    choice = random.choice(binaryChoice)
    print (choice)
```