# How to add random number using awk command?

Tags: awk

For Example I have a file having below lines .

```
A,B,C
E,F,G
H,I,J
```

I want the output like as follows .

```
A,B,C,0
E,F,G,1
H,I,J,2
```

I want to add a random number in the end . Can any one help me out in this ?

Comment: What kind of randomness? Evenly distributed? What have you tried so far? What doesn't work?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Random numbers generation with awk in BASH shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4048378/random-numbers-generation-with-awk-in-bash-shell)

Comment: `0, 1, 2` don't look very random... are you sure you mean random and not sequential?

Comment: I have tried below command . awk -F, ' {i=0; OFS=","} {print $1,$2,$3,i+1}' a.txt . I have received o/p like as below .                                                                        A,A,A,1
B,B,B,1
C,C,C,1
D,D,D,1                                                                                                         I want any random number to be printed line by line .even the number is in sequential order not a problem  . The number should n't be repeated next time .

Comment: relevant: https://xkcd.com/221/

Comment: You said: `The number should n't be repeated next time .` Even if it is very unlikely, even a perfect random generator can produce the same output twice in a row. That's the nature of randomness. If you need to make sure that the same numbers don't repeat you need a sequence generator which makes sure that any number it produces will be produces only once.

Answer (score 1):

`awk` to the rescue!

what you want to add is not a random number but a sequence number (random numbers might collide)

here is the script with the test case

```
$ printf "%s\n" {A..I} | paste -d, - - - | 
  awk '{print $0 "," NR-1}'

A,B,C,0
D,E,F,1
G,H,I,2
```

Answer (score 1):

According to conditions:

- ***to add a random number in the end***
- ***the number should not be repeated next time***

awk solution with ***randomizer*** generating random integer number:

```
awk 'function randint(n){ return int(n * rand()) }
     BEGIN{ FS=OFS="," }
     { 
         rn=randint(++c);            # rn - random number 
         if (rn in a) {              # if the number had been shown before
             do { 
                 rn=randint(c+3*2)   # generate new random number
             } 
             while (rn in a)         # until a unique number is obtained
         } 
         a[rn]; $4=rn                # add new random number as last field
     }1' file
```

An exemplary output:

```
A,B,C,0
E,F,G,6
H,I,J,5
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like what you want is a *sequential* number. Here's an **awk** solution:

```
awk '{printf "%s,%s\n", $0, p++}' input.txt
```