# Understaning stdin, stderr, stdout

Tags: linux, bash

I want to write a script that will:

- read a text stream on stdin
- print every 10th line on stderr
- print a random* line on stdout

I tried

```
#!/bin/bash

count=0
while IFS= read -r line; do

        awk '{if(NR%3==0) print $line}' >&2
        awk '{if(( RANDOM % 2 )) print $line}' >&1
done
```

However, RANDOM is not working.
What is wrong here? How to fix this?

Comment: it should be ${RANDOM}

Comment: @yakoudbz `${RANDOM}` is not working.

Comment: The RANDOM environment variable is a bash feature, it doesn't make sense in itself in awk. You could use double-quotes or similar to have the variable expanded, but it looks like [awk has its own random number generation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4048378/random-numbers-generation-with-awk-in-bash-shell) which you should probably use

Answer (score 0):

You must assing the RANDOM bash variable value as awk variables before using it. The random line must be something like:

```
awk -v random="$RANDOM" -v aline="$line" 'BEGIN {if(random % 2) print aline}' >&1
```