# bash - replace string between two keywords with different random numbers for each line

Tags: json, bash, awk, sed

I have got a json file whose content is like below:

```
cat myjson.json
[
    {"a":"1", "b":"c BEGIN END"},
    {"a":"2", "b":"d BEGIN END"},
    {"a":"3", "b":"e BEGIN END"},
    {"a":"4", "b":"f BEGIN END"}
]
```

What I need to do is transform this file to something like below

```
cat myjson.json
[
    {"a":"1", "b":"c BEGIN 12341 END"},
    {"a":"2", "b":"d BEGIN 43234 END"},
    {"a":"3", "b":"e BEGIN 53474 END"},
    {"a":"4", "b":"f BEGIN 54236 END"}
]
```

That is, inserting a random number between BEGIN and END keywords and this random number have to be different for each line.

I tried constructing below command

```
awk '{$0=gensub(/BEGIN(.*?)END/, "BEGIN $RANDOM END", "g", $0)}1' myjson.json
```

but the result is like below:

```
awk '{$0=gensub(/BEGIN(.*?)END/, "BEGIN $RANDOM END", "g", $0)}1' myjson.json
[
    {"a":"1", "b":"c BEGIN $RANDOM END"},
    {"a":"2", "b":"d BEGIN $RANDOM END"},
    {"a":"3", "b":"e BEGIN $RANDOM END"},
    {"a":"4", "b":"f BEGIN $RANDOM END"}
]
```

Instead of generating random number, it printed $RANDOM as is. How can I overcome this?

PS: I cannot use any third party tools/libraries. I have to do it in bash and I can only use sed or awk because real file has a lot of lines and I have to do it very fast.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: replace `$RANDOM` with `int(rand()*100000)`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4048378/random-numbers-generation-with-awk-in-bash-shell

Comment: awk '{$0=gensub(/BEGIN(.*?)END/, "BEGIN int(rand()*100000) END", "g", $0)}1' myjson.json        [
        {"a":"1", "b":"c BEGIN int(rand()*100000) END"},
        {"a":"2", "b":"d BEGIN int(rand()*100000) END"},
        {"a":"3", "b":"e BEGIN int(rand()*100000) END"},
        {"a":"4", "b":"f BEGIN int(rand()*100000) END"}
    ]  JNevill

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this `awk`:

```bash
awk '
function rnd() { # generates random num between 10K and 100K
   return int(rand()*100000-1)+10000
}
BEGIN { srand() } # seed the random
{
   print gensub(/(BEGIN)\s+(END)/, "\\1 " rnd() " \\2", "1")
}' file.json

[
    {"a":"1", "b":"c BEGIN 70514 END"},
    {"a":"2", "b":"d BEGIN 99405 END"},
    {"a":"3", "b":"e BEGIN 32648 END"},
    {"a":"4", "b":"f BEGIN 75761 END"}
]
```

Comment: Thank you, this did the trick for random numbers. Could you please give a hint about how to achieve the same for random string? Is that possible? Like BEGIN aWkHt END, again different random string for each line?

Comment: To ask a new question, create a new question.

Comment: @lupus: Meanwhile [you can take a look at this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/428737/how-can-i-add-random-string-for-each-line)

Comment: Also, this doesn't guarantee the uniqueness of the numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Perl to the rescue!

```
perl -pe '$r = int(rand 9000) + 1000; s/BEGIN END/BEGIN $r END/' myjson.json
```

- `-p` reads the input line by line, runs the code for each line and prints the result;
- See [rand](https://perldoc.pl/rand) and [int](https://perldoc.pl/int) for details, the formula creates random numbers in the interval of 1000 - 9999.

To make the numbers unique, you can use

```
perl -MList::Util=shuffle -pe '
    BEGIN { @r = shuffle(1000 .. 9999) }; s/BEGIN END/BEGIN $r[$i++] END/
' myjson.json
```

- See [List::Util](https://perldoc.pl/List::Util) for details on `shuffle`;
- It first shuffles the list of numbers 1000 .. 9999 randomly, then inserts the shuffled numbers one by one into the strings.

Comment: Thank you very much, buth I need to run the script in a customised linux environment and I am not sure I can use perl in the environment.