# AWK: subset randomly and without replacement a string in every row of a file

Tags: random, awk, subset, repeat, shuffle

So I need to subset 10 characters from all strings in a particular column of a file, randomly and without repetition (i.e. I want to avoid drawing a character from any given index more than once).

For the sake of simplicity, let's say I have the following string:

```
ABCDEFGHIJKLMN
```

For which I should obtain, for example, this result:

```
DAKLFCHGBI
```

Notice that no letter occurs twice, which means that no position is extracted more than once.

For this other string:

```
CCCCCCCCCCCCGG
```

Analogously, I should never find more than two "G" characters in the output (otherwise it would mean that a "G" character has been sampled more than once), e.g.:

```
CCGCCCCCCC
```

Or, in other words, I want to shuffle all characters from each string, and keep the first 10. This can be easily achieved in bash using:

```
echo "ABCDEFGHIJKLMN" | fold -w1 | shuf -n10 | tr -d '\n'
```

However, since I need to perform this many times on dozens of files with over a hundred thousand lines each, this is way too slow. So looking around, I've arrived at the following awk code, which seems to work fine whenever the strings are passed to it one by one, e.g.:

```
awk '{srand(); len=length($1); for(i=1;i<=10;) {k=int(rand()*len)+1; if(!(k in N)) {N[k]; printf "%s", substr($1,k,1); i++}} print ""}' <(echo "ABCDEFGHIJKLMN")
```

But when I input the following file with a string on each row, awk hangs and the output gets truncated on the second line:

```
echo "ABCDEFGHIJKLMN" > file.txt
echo "CCCCCCCCCCCCGG" >> file.txt

awk '{srand(); len=length($1); for(i=1;i<=10;) {k=int(rand()*len)+1; if(!(k in N)) {N[k]; printf "%s", substr($1,k,1); i++}} print ""}' file.txt
```

This other version of the code which samples characters from the string *with repetition* works fine, so it looks like the issue lies in the part which populates the N array, but I'm not proficient in awk so I'm a bit stuck:

```
awk '{srand(); len=length($1); for(i=1;i<=10;i++) {k=int(rand()*len)+1; printf "%s", substr($1,k,1)} print ""}'
```

Anyone can help?

In case this matters: my actual file is more complex than the examples provided here, with several other columns, and unlike the ones in this example, its strings may have different lengths.

Thanks in advance for your time :)

**EDIT:**

As mentioned in the comments, I managed to make it work by removing the N array (so that it resets before processing each row):

```
awk 'BEGIN{srand()} {len=length($1); for(i=1;i<=10;) {k=int(rand()*len)+1; if(!(k in N)) {N[k]; printf "%s", substr($1,k,1); i++}} split("", N); print ""}' file.txt
```

Do note however that if the string in $1 is shorter than 10, this will get stuck in an infinite loop, so make sure that all strings are always longer than the subset target size. The alternative solution provided by Andre Wildberg in the comments doesn't carry this issue.

Comment: please update the question to describe what your operation is doing; it's not clear (to me) what you mean by *`subset`*, especially in light of the fact that the 2 sample input strings are reduced in length; how can you say (for the first sample) that no letter can occur twice, but then for the 2nd string you say `G` can occur no more than *`twice`* while allowing `C` to occur 9 times ... ???????

Comment: also update the question to explain what you mean by `*But it breaks`* ... error message? 'wrong' output (and how do you know it's wrong)? no output? it hangs? something else?

Comment: one major issue I see ... you conditionally increment `i` (`i++`) if a value is not an index in the array; if you get to the point where the array is fully populated (ie, `k` is always in `N`) before `i==10` then you can end up in an infinite loop (ie, `i` is never incremented past `10` so you'll never exit the `for` loop); I'd suggest you rethink the 'logic' for determining when to increment `i` and/or add more logic to insure you can break out of the `for` loop once the array is full (however you define 'full')

Comment: at the end of the question, are you saying that the `echo|fold|shuf|tr` code does what you want? if 'yes'  ... would I be right in guessing that your objective is to scramble/shuffle the letters in the string and then print the first 10 characters to output?  and if this is correct, how did you decide on looping 10 times in the `awk/for` loop (ie, why not 3, or 20, or 3000)?

Comment: @markp-fuso thank you so much for your input. I've edited my post to try to answer your questions. Hopefully it's a bit more clear now. I'm looping over the strings 10 times in order to extract exactly 10 random and independent positions, but I guess there must be other (more efficient) ways to achieve this. I believe the issue with my code lies indeed in the part where N becomes populated, as you mentioned, but I'm not proficient in awk, and I've been stuck with this for a while now. Thanks again for your input!

Comment: Well, it looks like deleting the N array with `split("", N)` after the for loop does the trick, but if anyone comes with a cleaner solution, I'm sure it'll be helpful.

Comment: You should only call `srand` once, in BEGIN. Consider: `seq 100 | awk '{ srand(); print int(rand()*100) }'`

Comment: adding an assertion that len>=10 seems prudent before looping. `delete N` seems more direct than using `split`.

Comment: @jhnc `split("",N)` is more portable than `delete N` as not all awks support `delete array` yet as that's not part of the POSIX spec yet, so far POSIX only defines `delete array[index]`, not `delete array`. Having said that, I couldn't name an awk version that doesn't support it.

Comment: @EdMorton Thanks, I'd just been going by the `onetrueawk` manpage.

Comment: @jhnc : for the love of God Allah Buddha and Lady Gaga, please don't rely on the so called `onetrueawk` for anything - it's ancient it's slow, it calculates many divisions and modulos not to `IEEE 754` spec (as in ::  it couldn't even do `2^64 % 10^10` correctly ), and couldn't handle null bytes either (`sprintf("%c", 0)` results in an empty string not a null byte in `onetrueawk`).

Answer (score 0):

I would harness GNU `AWK` for this task following way, let `file.txt` content be

```
ABCDEFGHIJKLMN
CCCCCCCCCCCCGG
```

then

```
awk 'function comp_func(i1, v1, i2, v2){return rand()-0.5}BEGIN{FPAT=".";PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="comp_func"}{s="";patsplit($0,arr);for(i in arr){s = s arr[i]};print substr(s,1,10)}' file.txt
```

might give output

```
NGLHCKEIMJ
CCCCCCCCGG
```

Explanation: I use custom [Array Traversal Control function](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Controlling-Array-Traversal.html) which does randomly decides which element should be considered greater. `-0.5` is used as `rand()` gives values from 0 to 1. For each line array `arr` is populated by characters of line, then traversed in random order to create `s` string which are characters shuffled, then `substr` used to get first 10 characters. You might elect to add counter which will terminate `for` loop if you have very long lines in comparison to number of characters to select.

*(tested in GNU Awk 5.0.1)*

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I tried it in two different environments, but unfortunately it didn't work in neither. I got the following error:

`awk: calling undefined function patsplit`

Comment: @Daweo : and there's absolutely no randomness in your code, since the `rand()` seed is always the default of `1`

Answer (score 0):

Iteratively construct a substring of the remaining letters.

Tested with

- awk version 20121220
- GNU Awk 4.2.1, API: 2.0
- GNU Awk 5.2.1, API 3.2
- mawk 1.3.4 20200120

```
% awk -v size=10 'BEGIN{srand()} {n=length($0); a=$0; x=0;
    for(i=1; i<=n; i++){x++; na=length(a); rnd = int(rand() * na + 1)
      printf("%s", substr(a, rnd, 1))
      a=substr(a, 1, rnd - 1)""substr(a, rnd + 1, na)
      if(x >= size){break}}
    print ""}' file.txt
CJFMKHNDLA
CGCCCCCCCC
```

In consecutive iterative runs remember to check if `srand` [works the way you expect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4048378/random-numbers-generation-with-awk-in-bash-shell/4048538#4048538) in your version of awk. If in doubt use `$RANDOM` or, better, `/dev/urandom`.

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted, and works like a charm. Thank you so much!! I just want to mention that although it's cleaner than my version, it's only around half as fast (just in case this helps someone in the future).

Comment: @Arynio Yea, I also made some benchmarks, they vary wildly between different awks. original-awk is 1/3 faster. mawk was 5% slower. gawk 5.2 10% faster, 4.2. 10% slower. Also depends on your libraries and OS.

Comment: Also, mawk in general is 6 times faster than original-awk, the gawks somewhere in between.

Comment: Thank you for the benchmarks. I'm afraid I don't have enough reputation to upvote you, but it says the feedback was recorded.

Comment: No worries, all good!

Comment: you can speed up a mawk version quite dramatically by precalculating length, using print instead of printf and not duplicating the loop counter: `mawk -v size=10 'BEGIN{ORS="";srand()} { n=length(a=$0); if(n<size)next; for (i=size; i--; n--) { r=int(rand()*n)+1; print substr(a,r,1); a=substr(a,1,r-1)substr(a,r+1) } print "\n" }' file.txt`

Comment: @jhnc Yep, a speed up of approx. 30%

Answer (score 0):

if u don't need to be strictly within `awk`, then `jot` makes it super easy :

> ```
> say you want 20 random characters between 
> "A" (ascii 65) and "N" (ascii 78), inc. repeats of same chars
> ```
>
> ---
>
> ```
> jot -s '' -c -r 20 65 78
> ```

```
ANNKECLDMLMNCLGDIGNL
```

Comment: Forgive me if I'm misunderstanding something, but can you apply `jot` to a string which already exists? Isn't its purpose to generate strings? I don't think this proposal answers my question, but nonetheless thank you for your time.