# Pick and print one of three strings at random in Bash script

Tags: bash, shell, random

How can print a value, either 1, 2 or 3 (at random). My best guess failed:

```
#!/bin/bash

1 = "2 million"
2 = "1 million"
3 = "3 million"

print randomint(1,2,3)
```

Comment: The minimal question is: pick one integer out of `{1, 2, 3}`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2556190/random-number-from-a-range-in-a-bash-script + arrays solves this.

Comment: what are those `1  = "2 million"` lines supposed to mean? They aren't valid bash constructs.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

To generate random numbers with bash use the `$RANDOM` internal Bash function:

```
arr[0]="2 million"
arr[1]="1 million"
arr[2]="3 million"

rand=$[ $RANDOM % 3 ]
echo ${arr[$rand]}
```

From bash manual for RANDOM:

> Each time this parameter is
>   referenced, a random integer between 0
>   and 32767 is generated.  The sequence
>   of random numbers may be initialized
>   by assigning a value to RANDOM.  If
>   RANDOM is unset,it  loses  its 
>   special  properties,  even if it is
>   subsequently reset.

Comment: `$[ ]` is a compatibility construct to support 1970s-era Bourne syntax; that construct is *not* found in more recent standards, and thus not guaranteed to be supported by more modern shells other than bash (which has historically included it). Since 1991, when POSIX sh was published, the *standardized* math construct has been `$(( ))`, so this should be `rand=$(( RANDOM % 3 ))`.

Comment: I would also suggest quoting -- as in, `echo "${arr[$rand]}"`; that way we won't have unexpected behavior with different values in IFS, or with array values that expand as globs. (For instance, if `IFS=0123456789`, then `echo ${arr[$rand}` without the quotes wouldn't print any number at all).

Comment: How about rand=$[ $RANDOM % ${#arr[@]} ] to avoid hardcoding 3?

Answer (score 9):

**Coreutils `shuf`**

Present in [Coreutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/shuf-invocation.html), this function works well if the strings don't contain newlines.

E.g. to pick a letter at random from `a`, `b` and `c`:

```
printf 'a\nb\nc\n' | shuf -n1
```

**POSIX eval array emulation + RANDOM**

Modifying Marty's `eval` technique to emulate arrays (which are non-POSIX):

```
a1=a
a2=b
a3=c
eval echo \$$(expr $RANDOM % 3 + 1)
```

This still leaves the `RANDOM` non-POSIX.

`awk`'s `rand()` is a POSIX way to get around that.

Comment: what is "shuf";  linux?   i don't see it on mac osx, and arrays are so ugly.  see following answer

Comment: @MartyMcGowan GNU non-POSIX as linked. Agree that arrays are ugly, but first option with shuf does not use the arrays. Agree that greater portability would be cool. I didn't know `set` could set the arguments as you proposed, that's interesting.

Answer (score 5):

64 chars alpha numeric string

```
randomString32() {
    index=0
    str=""

    for i in {a..z}; do arr[index]=$i; index=`expr ${index} + 1`; done
    for i in {A..Z}; do arr[index]=$i; index=`expr ${index} + 1`; done
    for i in {0..9}; do arr[index]=$i; index=`expr ${index} + 1`; done
    for i in {1..64}; do str="$str${arr[$RANDOM%$index]}"; done

    echo $str
}
```

Comment: I believe this does not answer the question: OP wants to pick one out of 3 strings, not generate a completely random one. And `/dev/random` is better for that.

Answer (score 1):

```
~.$ set -- "First Expression" Second "and Last"
~.$ eval echo \$$(expr $RANDOM % 3 + 1)
and Last
~.$
```

Answer (score 1):

Want to corroborate using `shuf` from coreutils using the nice `-n1 -e` approach.

Example usage, for a random pick among the values `a`, `b`, `c`:

```sh
CHOICE=$(shuf -n1 -e a b c)
echo "choice: $CHOICE"
```

I looked at the balance for two samples sizes (1000, and 10000):

```
$ for lol in $(seq 1000); do shuf -n1 -e a b c; done > shufdata
$ less shufdata | sort | uniq -c
    350 a
    316 b
    334 c
```

```
$ for lol in $(seq 10000); do shuf -n1 -e a b c; done > shufdata
$ less shufdata | sort | uniq -c
   3315 a
   3377 b
   3308 c
```

Ref: https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/shuf-invocation.html