# how to rewrite a url link to a random generated url

Tags: php, .htaccess

i would like to make a page that's for example (http://casisxa.com/wp-content/upgrade/index.php/) to be viewed as (http://casisxa.com/wp-content/id=2376651/) whenever it is been clicked on rewriting the “/upgrade/index.php” directory to id=6637882 or id=2376651 or to a random generated link with such end. is there a .htaccess file that can do this. Please help me.

Comment: you can use redirect header for this

Comment: So you want to get a friendly Url and make it unfriendly? Never seen it done that way round before ... Might be worth telling us what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

You can either do it in php, something like:

```
<?php
header("Location: http://casisxa.com/wp-content/id=" . rand(1,9999999));
exit;
?>
```

Or you can use a rewrite map that invokes a program that generates the random number:

```
RewriteMap rand prg:/path/to/script

RewriteRule ^/?wp-content/upgrade/index.php/?$ /wp-content/id=$(rand:1) [L,QSA]
```

Where the `/path/to/script` is a script that generates a random number, something like this: [Random number from a range in a Bash Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2556190/random-number-from-a-range-in-a-bash-script)

The `RewriteMap` directive can only be used in the server or vhost config, not in htaccess files. But for all of this trouble, you may as well just use php.