# Shell Scripting: How to choose a randow number from three values?

Tags: shell, random

I want to write a Shell Script.
The task is, that I have to pick a random number.
But the numbers must be one of the following three.
5,10,15
So if "let's say" 'a' is smaller than 5, I have to pick randomly a number of 5,10 or 15.
How can I do that?

Comment: What if the number `a`, is greater than 5?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Random number from a range in a Bash Script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2556190/random-number-from-a-range-in-a-bash-script)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following

```
#!/bin/bash

arr=(5 10 15);
picked_element=${arr[$(($RANDOM % 3))]};
echo $picked_element;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a hint to help you do this.

First, create a variable (array) containing your 3 values : `arr = (5 10 15)`.

Then, create a [random number](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/randomvar.html) called `index` and floor it to 2.

Finally, retrieve the number `${arr[$index]}`.

Comment: Your link suggests using modulo, not floor. But even [modulo isn't sufficient](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10984974/113632) for uniform random numbers in a given range.