# Generating random numbers based on a +/- input

Tags: bash, shell, random

I’d like to generate a random number in a given range depending if the input is `+` or `-`.

For a positive input I would get a positive number between x and y (4 and 42 actually), for a negative input a number between -6 and -72.

In other words, if the input is `+`, then `rand(4,42)`, if the input is `-`, then `rand(-6,-72)`.

I’m just not sure how to string it all together.

Comment: The goal is that you add some code of your own to your question to show at least the research effort you made to solve this yourself.

Comment: Your question should also make clear that you're trying to do this in bash (not just using the "bash" tag).

Comment: It is good to use some formatting and spacing to make the post more readable.
There is no need for "Thank you" notes.

Comment: See also [Random number from a range in a Bash Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2556190/random-number-from-a-range-in-a-bash-script)

Answer (score 0):

```
function myrand() {
    MIN=$1
    MAX=$2
    DELTA=$(( $MAX - $MIN ))
    R=$(( $MIN + $(( RANDOM % $DELTA )) ))
    echo $R
}
echo $(( -1 * $(myrand 6 72) ))
echo $(myrand 4, 42)
```

Comment: While this code could solve the problem, it is best to add elaboration and explain how it works for people who might not understand this piece of code.

Comment: Better yet, don't encourage off-topic questions by answering them .

Answer (score 0):

Pure `bash`.  Mostly uniform random numbers, (might skew a bit low, but probably good enough), as per *OP* spec.  Feed it input from *numbers.txt*:

```
while read x; do echo $((x>=0?RANDOM%39+4:-RANDOM%67+6)); done < numbers.txt
```

How it works:  the arithmetic *expr?expr:expr*
              conditional operator is used to test `$x`, and return an appropriate value, derived from the *15-bit* built in `$RANDOM` variable.