# Difference between RANDOM and SRANDOM in Bash

Tags: bash, random

Bash 5.1 introduces `SRANDOM` variable, but does it make any difference when used like this?

```sh
for i in {1..10}; do
  nbr=$((RANDOM%50))
  nbr1=$((SRANDOM%50))
  echo "$nbr -- $snbr"
done
9 -- 21
35 -- 43
27 -- 15
7 -- 24
41 -- 31
37 -- 35
23 -- 47
14 -- 23
9 -- 37
6 -- 30
```

From [the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Variables.html):

> ### RANDOM
>
> Each time this parameter is referenced, it expands to a random integer between 0 and 32767. Assigning a value to this variable seeds the random number generator. If RANDOM is unset, it loses its special properties, even if it is subsequently reset
>
> ### SRANDOM
>
> This variable expands to a 32-bit pseudo-random number each time it is referenced. The random number generator is not linear on systems that support /dev/urandom or arc4random, so each returned number has no relationship to the numbers preceding it. The random number generator cannot be seeded, so assignments to this variable have no effect. If SRANDOM is unset, it loses its special properties, even if it is subsequently reset.

I don't understand what is meant by *non-linear* and *seeding*, but for my example is there a reason to use `RANDOM` over `SRANDOM` or vice-versa, or it doesn't make any difference?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`RANDOM` (16-bit) vs `SRANDOM` (32-bit); 32-bit => much bigger random numbers (ie, more random numbers).

As for the randomness of the 2x variables ...

Try running:

```
RANDOM=5; for i in {1..10}; do echo $RANDOM; done
RANDOM=5; for i in {1..10}; do echo $RANDOM; done
RANDOM=5; for i in {1..10}; do echo $RANDOM; done
```

You should find that each loop generates the same set of 'random' numbers:

```
18499
9909
24640
15572
5516
17897
19000
12793
27730
5509
```

Here's a [bash fiddle](http://tpcg.io/lfnXHOKK) of the above that generates the same exact output!

Another test:

```
RANDOM=5; echo $RANDOM $RANDOM
RANDOM=5; echo $RANDOM $RANDOM
RANDOM=5; echo $RANDOM $RANDOM
```

Repeatedly generates:

```
18499 9909
```

Now repeat this test but with `SRANDOM` and you should find that you cannot seed `SRANDOM` and therefore each iteration generates a different set of 'random' numbers.

```
SRANDOM=5; echo $SRANDOM $SRANDOM
SRANDOM=5; echo $SRANDOM $SRANDOM
SRANDOM=5; echo $SRANDOM $SRANDOM
```

Which generates 3 different sets of output:

```
1355214790 3304840972
4217276959 255499591
446827805 3301635911
```

**NOTE**: Thanks to [oguz ismail](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10248678/oguz-ismail) for the `SRANDOM` output.

---

As for the `linear` comment ...

As [President James K Polk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/238704/president-james-k-polk) mentioned in his comment, `'linear'` probably refers to the underlying algorithm by which `RANDOM` generates its not-so-random data.

Seeing how the `RANDOM` output can be determined beforehand (given a starting point, aka `seed`), I'd probably replace `'linear'` with something more along the lines of `'deterministic'` ...

---

Net result ... use `RANDOM` if you need to repeat a series of 'random' numbers ... use `SRANDOM` if you need to generate a set of truly random numbers.

Comment: As for the `linear` comment, if sequential values are linearly related they are correlated, making the sequence much easier to predict.

Comment: Also important, `RANDOM`, due to the seed, can be used to create.resulta that can be reproduced exactly which is handy for debugging and verification. With `SRANDOM` this is not possible. Results will be always different one way or another.

Comment: As of sizes, `RANDOM` is a **positive 16 bits signed integer** (0-32767) while `SRANDOM` is really a **32 bits unsigned integer**. It would be better to write something like: _RANDOM (15 bits unsigned) and SRANDOM (32 bits unsigned)_.