# How do I create 100 files with 1 random number in each of them and give them permissions based on the number

Tags: bash, shell

I need to create a bash script that creates 100 files with random numbers in them.
I tried to do it using:

```
for i in {1..100}; do $RANDOM > RANDOM.txt
```

I don't know if that's the correct way to do it.
And then I need to give the files reading writing and execution permissions based on the number inside the file. No idea how to do that.
I tried using:

```
if [ $i%2==0 ]
then
echo chmod +rw $RANDOM.txt
```

but that doesn't seem to work

Just got some feedback, it turns out I was doing everything wrong.
I had to create 100 files 1.txt to 100.txt I used touch {1..100}.txt and then paste 1 random number in each of those files. Should I use echo or shuf to do this?

Comment: Are the files supposed to have random names, too? Is the name the same as the random number in it?

Comment: You are on the right track. Create a bash script first. Create a loop from 1 to 10 and print that number. Once that is successful, in that loop, write the number to a file using something like echo $NUM > ${NUM}.txt. Once you have that working, add $NUM % 2 or whatever `if` logic you prefer. chmod 644 ${NUM}.txt if it meets the if logic, otherwise chmod 640 ${NUM}.txt. Once that works, all you have to do is find a way to change from static number to random. You can use  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2556190/random-number-from-a-range-in-a-bash-script for that.

Answer (score 3):

I think it'd be simplest to use `chmod` with octal permissions, like `0777` for `rwxrwxrwx` etc.

Example:

```
#!/bin/bash

for((i=0; i<100; ++i)) {
    rnd=$RANDOM                     # pick a random number
    (( perm = rnd % 512 ))          # make it in the range [0, 512) (0000-0777 oct)
    printf -v octperm "%04o" $perm  # convert to octal

    file=$rnd.txt                   # not sure if you meant to name it after the number
    echo $rnd > $file

    chmod $octperm $file            # chmod with octal number
}
```

Excerpt of files:

```
-r-xrw--wx 1 ted users   5 15 dec 17.53 6515.txt
---x-wxrwx 1 ted users   5 15 dec 17.53 6751.txt
-rwx-w--w- 1 ted users   5 15 dec 17.53 8146.txt
-rw-r----- 1 ted users   5 15 dec 17.53 8608.txt
--w--w---x 1 ted users   5 15 dec 17.53 8849.txt
--wx----wx 1 ted users   5 15 dec 17.53 8899.txt
--wxrwx-wx 1 ted users   5 15 dec 17.53 8955.txt
-rw-r-xrw- 1 ted users   5 15 dec 17.53 9134.txt
...
```

---

If you want to take your current `umask` into consideration, you could do that too, by masking away the bits in the permission indicated by the `umask`.

```
#!/bin/bash

(( um = ~$(umask) ))  # bitwise negated umask

for((i=0; i<100; ++i)) {
    rnd=$RANDOM

    (( perm = (rnd % 01000) & um ))    # [0000,0777] bitwise AND umask
    printf -v octperm "%04o" $perm

    file=$i.$rnd.txt                   # using $i. to make name unique
    echo $rnd > $file

    chmod $octperm $file
}
```

If your `umask` is currently `0022` the above example would not create any files writeable for *group* and/or *others* while the other (normal) permissions would be random.

Comment: Avoid useless fork! Use: `printf -v octperm "%04o" "$perm"`

Comment: @F.Hauri Oh, I didn't think that would fork. I'll check this out in an hour. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Have a look at [my version of your script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70368743/1765658)

Comment: @F.Hauri I just tried it out and it became 43% quicker with your suggestion. Many thanks!

Comment: This will create less than 100 files in case there is a collision in the generated random numbers.

Comment: @M.NejatAydin Yes absolutely. I made a note about the naming in the code. I wasn't sure what OP wanted really. To get a unique name, `$i.` could be inserted somewhere in the name. I added that to the second example to show how it could be done.

Comment: @F.Hauri I _am_ the one who has upvoted your answer :-) Edit: Oh, you meant the actual comment. Sure, yes, done.

Answer (score 2):

First, you need to echo the random number, not use it as a command.

Second, if you want to use the same random number as the filename and content, you need to save it to a variable. Otherwise you'll get a different number each time you write `$RANDOM`.

Third, that's not how you do arithmetic and conditions inside `[]`, any shell scripting tutorial should show the correct way. You can also use a bash arithmetic expression with `(( expression ))`.

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in {1..100}
do
    r=$RANDOM
    echo "$r" > "$r.txt"
    if (( i % 2 == 0 ))
    then
        chmod +rw "$r.txt"
    fi
done
```

Comment: can I use more than one condition using this model?
#!/bin/bash
rm -r -f *.txt
for i in {1..100}
do
r=$RANDOM
echo "$r" > "$r.txt"
if (( i % 2 == 0 ))
then chmod +rw "$r.txt"
elif (( i % 3 == 0 ))
then
chmod +rwx "$r.txt"
else
chmod -r "$r.txt"
fi
done

Comment: Of course, why would you think otherwise?

Answer (score 1):

### Another approach

Strictly answering your question:

```bash
for file in file{10001..10100}; do
    ((rnd=RANDOM))
    echo $rnd > ${file/10/-}
    ((rnd%2)) || chmod ugo+rw ${file/10/-}
done
```

This will produce 100 files, named `file-001` to `file-100`:

- `file{10001..10100}` will generate an *array of strings* containing `[file10001 file10002 ... file10099 file10100]`.
- `for file in ...` will loop over this array using `$file` variable name.
- `${file/10/-}` will expand `$file` variable by replacing 1st occurence of `10` by a dash `-`.

```bash
/bin/ls -l|sed '7,95d'
total 400
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 6 31 déc 10:32 file-001
-rw-rw-rw- 1 user user 5 31 déc 10:32 file-002
-rw-rw-rw- 1 user user 5 31 déc 10:32 file-003
-rw-rw-rw- 1 user user 6 31 déc 10:32 file-004
-rw-rw-rw- 1 user user 6 31 déc 10:32 file-005
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 5 31 déc 10:32 file-095
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 6 31 déc 10:32 file-096
-rw-rw-rw- 1 user user 5 31 déc 10:32 file-097
-rw-rw-rw- 1 user user 5 31 déc 10:32 file-098
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 6 31 déc 10:32 file-099
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 6 31 déc 10:32 file-100
```

### From [Ted Lyngmo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70367471/1765658)

With some *bashisms*, like *using integer variables properties* and *avoiding forks*...

```bash
declare -i um=" ~$(umask) " i rnd perm
for((i=100;i--;)){
     rnd=RANDOM
     perm=' ( rnd % 01000 ) & um | 384'
     printf -v file file-%03d-%04X.txt $i $rnd
     printf -v octperm "%04o" "$perm"
     echo "$rnd" > "$file"
     chmod "$octperm" "$file"
}
```

(Filename is built with file number as decimal AND random number in hexadecimal)

This could produce something like:

```bash
/bin/ls -l|sed '7,95d'
total 400
-rw---xr-x 1 user user 5 31 déc 10:49 file-000-228D.txt
-rwx------ 1 user user 6 31 déc 10:49 file-001-3F42.txt
-rw---x--x 1 user user 5 31 déc 10:49 file-002-0A19.txt
-rwxr-xr-x 1 user user 5 31 déc 10:49 file-003-057F.txt
-rw------x 1 user user 6 31 déc 10:49 file-004-6F81.txt
-rw---x--- 1 user user 6 31 déc 10:49 file-094-599A.txt
-rw------x 1 user user 5 31 déc 10:49 file-095-1511.txt
-rw---xr-x 1 user user 6 31 déc 10:49 file-096-6F0F.txt
-rwxr-x--x 1 user user 6 31 déc 10:49 file-097-6BE9.txt
-rwx--xr-- 1 user user 5 31 déc 10:49 file-098-12CE.txt
-rwx--x--x 1 user user 6 31 déc 10:49 file-099-314B.txt
```

#### About performances

Maybe a little quicker, because of avoiding forks and using integers.

(  The `for((;;)){ ;}` syntax used here is not quicker, just different (shorter)...
In fact, `for ((i=100;i--;)) ;do ...;done` is (insensibly) slower than `for i in {1..100};do ...;done`! I just wanted to use this unusual syntax for *extreme bashism*... ;)

Some comparison:

```bash
export TIMEFORMAT=$'(%U + %S) / \e[1m%R\e[0m : %P'
```

About *forks*, trying 1'000 variable assignment for formatting, using `printf`:

```bash
time for i in {1..1000};do var=$(printf "foo");done 
(0.773 + 0.347) / 1.058 : 105.93

time for i in {1..1000};do printf -v var "foo";done 
(0.006 + 0.000) / 0.006 : 99.80
```

From 1.058 seconds to 6 milliseconds on my host!!! There are no discussion: *forks* (syntax `$(printf...)`) is to be avoided!!

About *integer properties* (using 100'000 binary operations):

```bash
declare -i intvar

time for i in {1..100000};do var=$(( ( 431214 % 01000 ) & -19 ));done
(0.272 + 0.005) / 0.278 : 99.46  

time for i in {1..100000};do intvar=' ( 431214 % 01000 ) & -19 ';done 
(0.209 + 0.000) / 0.209 : 99.87
```

From 0,28 seconds to 0.21 seconds, this is less significant, but approx 1/4 quicker.

About `for i in {` vs `for ((i=` (now using 1'000'000 loops):

```bash
time for i in {1..1000000};do :;done
(1.600 + 0.000) / 1.602 : 99.86

time for ((i=1000000;i--;));do :;done
(1.880 + 0.001) / 1.882 : 99.95
```

But this is clearly less significant (care about memory consumption, using braces!).

Comment: This is a few percent faster than my current version. Nice! ... but if I change to `for i in {1..100};do` it's actually about the same speed as my version.

Comment: I ran a multitude of tests and on my machine looping to 10000 and the `for i in {1..10000}` loop was consistently slower than the `for((i=0; i<10000; ++i)) {` version. Could be a difference in version perhaps. I used "GNU bash, version 5.1.0(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)" in my tests.

Comment: Added performance comparison, have a look

Comment: Hmm, I can't explain the diff. I timed the whole script, creating 10000 files using the two different loops (where the only difference was the loop). Consistent results. If I shrink the script down to a loop only printing the value of `$i` (and piping the script output to `/dev/null`) the result is exactly like you've shown. Very interesting.

Comment: @TedLyngmo New edit, the last one for 2023! Happy new year!

Answer (score 0):

With `awk`, you could try following once. This program also take care of closing the open files in backend(in case we get error "too many files opened" once). Written and tested in GNU `awk`.

```
awk -v numberOfFiles="100" '
BEGIN{
  srand()
  for(i=1;i<=numberOfFiles;i++){
    out=(int(1 + rand() * 10000))
    print out > (out".txt")
    system("chmod +rw " out".txt")
    close(out)
  }
}'
```

I have created an `awk` variable named `numberOfFiles` where I have given `100`(as per need to create 100 files), you can keep it as per your need too, in future if you need to change it and we need not to change anything in rest of program here.