# bash grep 'random matching' string

Tags: bash, random, grep

Is there a way to grab a 'random matching' string via bash from a text file?

I am currently grabbing a download link via bash, curl & grep from a online text file.

Example:

```
DOWNLOADSTRING="$(curl -o - "http://example.com/folder/downloadlinks.txt" | grep "$VARIABLE")"
```

from online text file which contains

```
http://alphaserver.com/files/apple.zip
http://alphaserver.com/files/banana.zip
```

where $VARIABLE is something the user selected.

Works great, but i wanted to add some mirrors to the text file.

So when the variable 'banana' is selected, text file which i grep contains:

```
http://alphaserver.com/files/apple.zip
http://betaserver.com/files/apple.zip
http://gammaserver.com/files/apple.zip
http://deltaserver.com/files/apple.zip
http://alphaserver.com/files/banana.zip
http://betaserver.com/files/banana.zip
http://gammaserver.com/files/banana.zip
http://deltaserver.com/files/banana.zip
```

the code should pick a random 'banana' string and store it as the 'DOWNLOADSTRING' variable. 
the current code above can only work with 1 string in the text file, since it grabs everything 'banana'.

What this is for; i wanted to add some mirror downloadlinks for the files in the online text file, and the current code doesn't allow that.

Can i let grep grab one random 'banana' string? (and not all of them)

Comment: Would it be enough to pick the first matched "string"? That can be done with `grep -m 1 banana` . Flag -m specifies the maximum number of found lines

Answer (score 3):

See this question to see how to get a random line after grep. `rl` seems like a good candidate

[What's an easy way to read random line from a file in Unix command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448005/whats-an-easy-way-to-read-random-line-from-a-file-in-unix-command-line)

then do a `grep ... | rl | head -n 1`

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
DOWNLOADSTRING="$(curl -o - "http://example.com/folder/downloadlinks.txt" | grep "$VARIABLE")" |
    sort -R | head -1
```

The output will be random-sorted and then the first line will be selected.

Comment: Note that "|" is a command separator (like ";") so you don't need the line continuation character "\"

Comment: I think I once knew that ! I'm saying that because I was not sure whether I need a backslash or not; but I put it anyway, to make sure. Thanks for pointing that out, I'll edit the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If `mirrors.txt` has the following data, which you provided in your question:

```
http://alphaserver.com/files/apple.zip
http://betaserver.com/files/apple.zip
http://gammaserver.com/files/apple.zip
http://deltaserver.com/files/apple.zip
http://alphaserver.com/files/banana.zip
http://betaserver.com/files/banana.zip
http://gammaserver.com/files/banana.zip
http://deltaserver.com/files/banana.zip
```

Then you can use the following command to get a random *"matched string"* from the file:

```
grep -E "${VARIABLE}" mirrors.txt | shuf -n1
```

Then you can store it as the variable `DOWNLOADSTRING` by setting it's value with a function call like so:

```
rand_mirror_call() { grep -E "${1}" mirrors.txt | shuf -n1; }
DOWNLOADSTRING="$(rand_mirror_call ${VARIABLE})"
```

This will give you a dedicated random line from the text file based on the user's `${VARIABLE}` input. It is a lot less typing this way.