# wget link from random line in file

Tags: bash, random, wget

I'm trying to download a website that uses semi-predictable urls, meaning the url will always end with a random five character alphanumeric string. I created a file with crunch with the random string by using the command:

```
crunch 5 5 abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz123456789 > possible_links
```

Then I created a bash file to call the lines and wget the links:

```
#!/bin/bash
FILE=possible_links
while read line; do
        wget -q --wait=20 www.ghostbin.com/paste/${line}
done < $FILE
```

but obviously it is going to go to aaaaa, then aaaab, then aaaac, aaaad, etc etc, is there a way to make it go to random lines?

Comment: `but obviously it is going to go to aaaaa` with out `done<"$FILE"` huh?

Comment: @sjsam yea i did a copy paste and didnt grab the < $FILE it doesnt have quotes though

Comment: Update the question then.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/448005/whats-an-easy-way-to-read-random-line-from-a-file-in-unix-command-line may have some useful thoughts.

Comment: use `mktemp --dry-run`

Comment: @Matt : My solution is specific to this problem, the link \@larsks pointed out give you many general solutions. Do have a look :-)

Comment: @sjsam i did, i was mid modifying the script when you posted your answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `mktemp --dry-run` option :

```
#!/bin/bash
while true # or specify a count using something like while [ $count -le 20 ]
do
rand_str="$(mktemp --dry-run XXXXX)" # 5 Xs for five random characters
  wget -q --wait=20 www.ghostbin.com/paste/${rand_str}
# if you use count increment count ie do '((count++))' else you get infinite loop
done
```

---

**General solution** (for n random characters)

```
str=$(printf "%-10s" "X") # here n=10
while condition
do
rand_str=$(mktemp --dry-run ${str// /X}) 
.
.
```