# Bash. How to assign random line from text file to a variable?

Tags: bash, text, variable-assignment

I have text file which contains numerous lines. I need to do:

1. shuf txt.txt
2. From shuf output read first line to a variable $line

How to represent it in one line for bash script?

Now it is like this:

```
shuf txt.txt -o aaa.txt
n=$(head -n 1 aaa.txt)
rm -rf aaa.txt
```

As you may notice, it is not very nice

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: I've done it in long way. I would like to know elegant way

Comment: `n=$(shuf txt.txt | head -n1)`

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: @oguzismail: `head -n1` is unnecessary. `n=$(shuf -n 1 file)`..

Comment: @I'L'I wew, I didn't know that. thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily do this with `shuf`:

```
n=$(shuf -n1 file)
```

↳ https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/shuf-invocation.html

<sub>Related question on stack overflow.com: [What's an easy way to read random line from a file in Unix command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/448005/499581)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like homework. Here's some hints.

Assigning a variable to the result of a command:

```
x=`command`
```

Assignment with pipe:

```
x=`command1 | command2`
```

Assigning the first line of command1's output to a variable:

```
x=`command1 | head -n1`
```